# Difference between lightning app builder and lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Can anyone here please explain me what is the difference between lightning app builder and lightning component? why do we have lightning app builder when we have lightning component and we can refer this component to a lightning application, And which can run on both mob app and desktop app (app which run on salesfroce platform). The lightning component can do different process but I am not able to add a flow to this lightning component. But on other hand lightning app builder can hold a VF page in which we can enable a flow. I need to enable a flow to a lightning component. Is this possible enable flow in lightning component.

Comment: You question starts from asking the difference between lightning comp. and lightning app builder and ends by asking how to enable flow in lightning. So what is you question?

Comment: @Ashwani I want to know what is the difference between lightning comp and lightning app builder, as we can enable flow in lightning app builder but not in  lightning comp why?

Comment: You should close this and ask your several questions separately, some of which are already answered on SFSE.

Answer (score 2):

Lightning App builder is a tool provided by Salesforce to build a lightning page by drag and drop of Lightning Components and Visualforce page into the page. Similar example can be process builder or community builder. It is a tool which admin can use.

Lightning components are small reusable applications which can be used in lightning pages. They are developed using apex and aura . It requires coding knowledge.

Comment: thanks @Ashwani, so you mean that Lightning components which are developed my a developer can be used in Lightning App builder right. But can we add a flow to a Lightning components.

Comment: Exactly. App builder is just a tool, you can configure it.

Comment: Can you provide any doc or example how to add a lightning component to lightning app builder? Because I have created a lightning component but not able to view those lightning component in my lightning app builder

Comment: @Anu Search for Salesforce Lightning Developer Guide, it is very helpful.